# ASP.Net MVC Strongly-Typed Forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between the following two Html.BeginForm syntax options:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitSiteSearch", "Home"))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SearchText, "Quick Search:");
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SearchText);
    @Html.SubmitButton("btn-quick-home-search", "Search");
}

@using (Html.BeginForm<HomeController>(x => x.SubmitSiteSearch(Model), FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SearchText, "Quick Search:");
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SearchText, new { id = "quick-home-search" });
    @Html.SubmitButton("btn-quick-home-search", "Search");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitSiteSearch(HomeViewModel model)
{
    string _siteSearchText = model.SearchText;
    return View(model);
}
```

The first form creates an instance of HomeViewModel and sets SearchText with the textbox value, while the second form does not.

Can someone explain the difference and/or how these should be used?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the second is not part of ASP.NET MVC. You are probably using some 3rd party library such as MVC Futures assembly for example. Assuming you are using the default routes both helpers should generate the same markup:

```
<form action="/Home/SubmitSiteSearch" method="post">
    <label for="SearchText">Quick Search:</label>
    <input id="SearchText" name="SearchText" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="btn-quick-home-search" name="btn-quick-home-search" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```